# How can I define a local function within another function in DAML?

Tags: daml

I'm trying to define a local function within another function but can't seem to get the syntax right. I have the following:

```haskell
foo : Int -> Bool
foo i =
  let bar j = j < 5
  bar i
```

But I'm getting a syntax error on the `bar`. What is the correct syntax to define such a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ordinary local function bindings, and variable bindings with `let` in general, you have to use `in` after all functions/variables have been defined:

```
  let bar j = j < 5
  in bar i
```

A `let` without `in` can be used within a `do` block *only*, in which case the variable is defined for the rest of the `do` block:

```
blah = do
  let bar j = j < 5
  assert $ not $ bar 5
  pure $ bar 5
```

However, that can only be used where it is valid to use `do`. Otherwise, use `in`.

A `where` clause can also be attached to a definition, in lieu of `let`:

```
foo i = bar i
  where bar j = j < 5
```

This use of `where` is unrelated to its role in `template` syntax.

Note that `where`, while it is nicer for some cases, is pretty restrictive about where (sorry) it can be used, whereas (sorry again) `let`/`in` works *anywhere* an expression is allowed:

```
foo i =
  let bar j = j < 5
  in bar (let q = 2 in i + q)
```

See [daml docs on let](https://docs.daml.com/daml/reference/expressions.html#let) and [this discussion of when to use let or where](https://wiki.haskell.org/Let_vs._Where).